# How to explain the result file produced by "g++ -fdump-lang-class" command?

Tags: c++, class, gcc, memory-management, g++

I want to learn the memory module in C++ class (like vtable, vptr...)
And I use "g++ -fdump-lang-class" to produce a .class file to show the class memory.

the test code like this:

```
class A {
public:
    void func() {}
private:
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void func() {}
private:
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

and the .class file show:

```
Class A
   size=4 align=4
   base size=4 base align=4
A (0x0x7f3a29771ae0) 0

Class B
   size=12 align=4
   base size=12 base align=4
B (0x0x7f3a296201a0) 0
  A (0x0x7f3a29771ba0) 0
```

I'm wondering about the meaning of "A (0x0x7f3a29771ae0) 0" in Class A and "A (0x0x7f3a29771ba0) 0" in Class B.

What's the "0x0x..." and "0"? And Why the two A is different?